# How to find and unmount unresponsive NFS mounts?

Tags: nfs

I turned off a machine exporting one folder which was mounted on my Mac using NFS.

How can I find and unmount the mount point ?

`df` does not return; it is probably stuck on this mount point, and I can't find a way to enumerate NFS mount points.

Answer (score 1):

The [`mount`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/mount.8.html) command on the command line should give a list of all mounts, along with the mount point and the used file system, so nfs mounts can be identified as such.

Comment: When  asked the question, neither df nor mount would return, but it looks like mount is less likely to hang in such case today, because I failed to reproduce the problem with a similar setup

Answer (score 0):

This command gave me useful informations:

```
$ sudo lsof | grep -i warning 
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() nfs file system /Volumes/antData
Output information may be incomplete.
assuming "dev=1a000005" from mount table
```

This gave me the mount point on the local machine, which I used as an argument to `umount -f`